# Send mail with Nuxt trough Sendgrid

Tags: sendgrid, nuxt.js

I have a simple vuetify contact form and I want to send this forms by email.
I have tried to use a `method` to send the email, but it does not work, because its on client side. So I get CORS issues.

Here's my code:

```
async send() {
  if (this.$refs.form.validate()) {
    try {
      const sgMail = require("@sendgrid/mail");
      sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
      const msg = {
        to: "test@example.com",
        from: "me@mydomain.com",
        subject: "Sending with SendGrid is Fun",
        text: "and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js",
        html: "<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js</strong>"
      };
      sgMail.send(msg);
    }
  }
}
```

Is Express (or an other backend) required? Is there a way to make it work using a middleware?

**EDIT**

Apparently, it's just not possible: https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/issues/730

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CORS policy from Sendgrid does not allow you to use their API from the browser (*The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://sendgrid.api-docs.io'*).

Quoted from *https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/cors/* :

> In SendGrid's case, we do not allow our customers to make a browser-based call to our v3/mail/send endpoint. (...)
>   You can create a server-based application, which will protect your API keys from being released to the world. Languages like NodeJS, PHP, Ruby, Python, C#, Go, and Java, and others can be implemented to make calls to the API from the security of a locked down server environment.

You have to send the email from a server, which is a good thing since your API Key would be exposed by the browser otherwise.

If you are using Nuxt in SSR mode (with Node running), I guess you could create a "Server Middleware" ( https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-servermiddleware ), for example with a path like "/api/mail", that will send the email.

If you are using *nuxt-generate* to create a static site, you can use a "function as a service", with something like "https://webtask.io/", to create a small node script; that you can trigger by url from your client to send the email.

Comment: Here is the message: `Access to fetch at 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send' from origin 'https://domain.herokuapp.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://sendgrid.api-docs.io' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Have the server send the header with a valid value, or, if an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

Comment: Okay, their CORS policy does not allow browsers to call their API (except if your are on "https://sendgrid.api-docs.io" domain)  ... You have to send email from your server, which is the best way to keep you API key secret